# Paging With Repeater

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq

I want to do paging in repeater control. I am using xml as a database with linq. So please give me suggestion how can do it.
I try this code but its not working

```cs
    public int RowCount
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)ViewState["RowCount"];
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["RowCount"] = value;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            FetchData(5, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
            CreatePagingControl();
        }

    }

    private void FetchData(int take,int pagesize)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/BlogContent.xml"));
        var result = doc.Descendants("post").Where(x => x.Element("id") != null).Take(take).Skip(pageSize)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            id = x.Element("id").Value,
            title = x.Element("title").Value,
            Description = x.Element("Discription").Value,
            dt = x.Element("dt").Value,
            mnt = x.Element("mnt").Value,
            yr = x.Element("yr").Value,
            postdate = x.Element("PostDate").Value
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.id);

        PagedDataSource page = new PagedDataSource();
        page.AllowPaging = true;
        page.AllowCustomPaging = true;
        page.DataSource = result;
        page.PageSize = 10;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            RowCount = result.Count();

        }





    }
    private void CreatePagingControl()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (RowCount / 10) + 1; i++)
        {
            LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.Click += new EventHandler(lbl_click);
            lnk.ID = "lnkPage" + (i + 1).ToString();
            lnk.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lnk);
            Label spacer = new Label();
            spacer.Text = "&nbsp;";
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(spacer);
        }


    }
    void lbl_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
        int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
        int take = currentPage * 10;
        int skip = currentPage == 1 ? 0 : take - 10;
        FetchData(take, skip);


    }
```

When i am using this code the previous and next buttons are working but data on repeater is not changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at :

```cs
void lbl_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
    int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
    int take = currentPage * 10;
    int skip = currentPage == 1 ? 0 : take - 10;
    FetchData(take, skip);  
}
```

What you are saying is that you will display 10 times the number of the currentpage in rows. For instance if you are in page 4 you are going to display 40 rows, whereas in page 5 you will display 50 rows.

Then you dictate how many rows to skip, so in first page you will skip none, but in page 4 you will skip 40 - 10 = 30 rows. What you should do is take always a predefined set of rows, ie 10 and then the skip to be a variable.

For instance you should have your code as:

```cs
void lbl_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
    int currentPage = int.Parse(lnk.Text);
    int take = 10;
    int skip = (currentPage - 1) * 10;
    FetchData(take, skip);  
}
```

In page 1 you will skip 0 rows, in page 2 10 rows etc.

You could even take under consideration on having the take number in a user defined variable...

**Edit**

You should also check your Page_Load

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FetchData(5, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
        CreatePagingControl();
    }

}
```

In the initial load of data you take the five first rows and skip 0. If you change that to

```cs
FetchData(10, 0);
```

you should be ok.

Giannis

Comment: but the problem not solved page numbering is not display correct its show only 1 and data in repeater for first time shows 5 posts but when i click on paging link then its show me 10 posts again. But in my xml i have only 10 post total

Comment: Then you may change 10 to 5, like: FetchData(5, 0); , int take = 5; and int skip = (currentPage - 1) * 5;. I would advise though having a variable or setting called RowsPerPage or something and then replacing 5 with that variable. Then the user or the administrator could change that value to his liking without changing the code...

Comment: i told u that i did it then the same  paging number problem :(

Comment: In the FetchData sub you have defined page.PageSize = 10; change that to 5.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but have you seen my previous comment about changing the PageSize property?